# jasmine.Clock VS sinon.clock what's wrong with my jasmin.Clock.useMock() usage?

Tags: javascript, tdd, coffeescript, jasmine, sinon

I'm just giving a try to unit testing in javascript/coffeescript with jasmine, very nice.

I've been trying to use jasmine.Clock.Mock() to advance in time and fire setTimeout callbacks.

Alas the jasmine.Clock.tick(1001) did not seem to have any effect ! 
I then discovered sinon.js that had its own time mock, and using this one it was allright. I'd like to understand why.

Here is a dummy jquery plugin to be tested:

```
dummy_method = function(callback) {
  fire_callback = function() {
    callback();
  }
  setTimeout("fire_callback()", 1000);
}
```

And here are both versions of the specs :

```
# Working test (spy was called as expected), using sinon FakeTimers
 describe "jQuery.fn.countdown", ->
   beforeEach () ->
     this.clock = sinon.useFakeTimers();
   afterEach () ->
     this.clock.restore()
   it 'should fireup the callback', ->
     countdown_callback = jasmine.createSpy('countdown_callback');

     dummy_method(countdown_callback)
     this.clock.tick(1001)
     expect(countdown_callback).toHaveBeenCalled()



# Non-working test (spy is never called), using jasmine Clock Mock
describe "jQuery.fn.countdown", ->
  beforeEach () ->
    jasmine.Clock.useMock()
  it 'should fireup the callback', ->
    countdown_callback = jasmine.createSpy('countdown_callback');

    dummy_method(countdown_callback)
    jasmine.Clock.tick(1001)
    expect(countdown_callback).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jasmine just try to call a function where sinon test if the passed argument is a function or a string. If its a string it call `eval`.

**Jasmine:**

```
jasmine.getGlobal().setTimeout = function(funcToCall, millis) {
  if (jasmine.Clock.installed.setTimeout.apply) {
    return jasmine.Clock.installed.setTimeout.apply(this, arguments);
  } else {
    return jasmine.Clock.installed.setTimeout(funcToCall, millis);
  }
};
```

**Sinon:**

```
if (typeof timer.func == "function") {
    timer.func.apply(null, timer.invokeArgs);
} else {
    eval(timer.func);
}
```

So this will pass the Jasmin test

```
setTimeout(fire_callback, 1000);
```

while this will fail

```
setTimeout("fire_callback()", 1000);
```

Comment: Damn right thanks ! I did not even know that a function object could  be passed to setTimeout and setInterval... Bad habit I guess :(